# Screen flow to capture second element

Tags: visual-workflow, screen-flow

Hi all I am new to screen flows. I have a requirement where I have to get the account of a contact of the logged in user and perform field update on the account object.
I can get the current user in the flow and get the contacts of the user but how do I then capture the accounts.
Can I get some inputs on this?

Comment: Contact has a lookup field to the Account; when you do Get Record on User, you will have access to parent Contact and grandparent Account.  Use [edit] to show what you have tried so far

Comment: @cropredy updated

Comment: If you do a Get Records on User with `Id = $User.Id`, the result will allow access to the user's contact->account lookups. But, since you haven't exposed more of your flow, I may be off here. Use [edit] to show more please

Comment: @cropredy Sorry I missed it. I have added the entire get records part. If this is correct can I get a suggestion on how to proceed in the update records part. I have added the screenshot of how I have done.

Comment: (1) - I forgot that `User.AccountId` exists, your use of it looks fine (2) Your `Get Accounts` element is misnamed - it is really `Get Current User`; (3) Your `Update Accounts` is trying to update the `Organization` object not the `Account` object

Comment: @cropredy Actually this organization is the API name of the Account object so it is working.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. You get a inbuilt flow variable called $User
2. Use a Get Record Element query on Contact to get Account Id by using Id = $User.ContactId
3. Then simply drag a Update Records Element set Object as Account Where Id = Contact.AccountId(Retrieved from Step2)

Answer (score 0):

Hi all I have fixed this issue by capturing the accountId from the user itself and then updating those particular records with the accountId matching.